# How do I use the "Add to Cart" button on shopify to redirect to my Etsy or eBay with subheadings "Purchase on Etsy" and "Purchase on eBay"

Tags: button, shopify, cart, buybutton.js

Really struggling here as it's my first website. I currently have the free Dawn theme, I'm trying to add buttons to all my product pages, instead of "add to cart", I'd like to change those buttons so they redirect to my etsy product page or eBay product page. A button that says "Purchase on etsy" which directs to my etsy page and vice versa.

I'm currently not equipped at the moment to have my shopify running as an actual store, and want to use it mostly as an inventory management system and be able to tag my products on instagram and facebook.

Thanks

Comment: use product meta fields to store the URL for the Etsy and eBay, and use on frontend instead of add to card.

Answer (score 0):

As Onkar mentioned, you can use Products Metafields to create new custom external purchase URL for the products.
Then use some CSS code to hide existing ADD TO CART button.
You can add new section "CUSTOM LIQUID" to display new external purchase button.